# Lua: Can I write two files simultaneously using the IO?

Tags: io, lua

Can I write two files simultaneously using the IO? Thanks!

Comment: You can cooperatively multitask via coroutines. To run simultaneously, you'll need a thread library of some kind. But you probably don't want to do parallel file IO if you can help it. What are your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your requirements on "simultaneous writing", in the simplest case you can open multiple files and interleave writes to both files:

```
local f1 = io.open('file1.txt', 'w')
local f2 = io.open('file2.txt', 'w')

f1:write('This will go to first file\n')
f2:write('Second file, Pi is: ', math.pi, '\n')
```

Comment: Is this really simultaneously (at the same time)? This is in ordered of f1 then f2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I suggesting this great read on [threading](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ThreadsTutorial). Threading allows for multiprocessing meaning running two things at once. In this case you are interested in writing files simultaneously